# How can I extrude SVG using three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am working on a project where I want to extrude SVG. Below is the SVG code.
How to extrude these SVG so that it rotates 360 degrees?

```
<style type="text/css">
.st0{fill:#F9F9F9;}
</style>

<path id="Floor" class="st0" d="M376.8,390.6L733.4,31.1C743.6,20.8,757.5,15,771.9,15h826.4c14.4,0,26,11.6,26,26v336.4
c0,12.4-7.6,23.5-19.2,28l-211.5,82c-22.5,9.7-38.1,30-41.1,53.5l-10,79.5c0,25-21.2,45.3-47.3,45.3h-54.9
c-111.7,0-216.3,52.5-279.8,140.5L806,1020.7c-15.5,21.5-41,34.3-68.2,34.3H392.3c-16.6,0-30-13.4-30-30V425.8
C362.3,412.6,367.5,400,376.8,390.6z, M1079.7,542.6h-73.1v73.1h73.1V542.6z, M904,569.2L904,569.2c8.9-8.9,8.9-23.5,0-32.4
l-49.5-49.5c-8.9-8.9-23.5-8.9-32.4,0l0,0c-7.8,7.8-7.8,20.5,0,28.3l53.6,53.6C883.5,577,896.3,577,904,569.2z, M643.9,603.8
l-33.7,0c-11.8,0-19.1,12.7-13.2,22.9l16.8,29.2c5.9,10.2,20.6,10.2,26.5,0l16.8-29.2C663,616.6,655.7,603.8,643.9,603.8z"/>
```

Comment: You can just follow the example here: https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-06/05-extrude-svg.html